# Stripe no charge for first 3 quantity for one year and charge if quantity added above 3 in first year

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-payments-js, stripe-payment-intent

I have a tiered price for 3 items for 120$. For the first year, I'm offering free. But if the customer buy the 4th item I need to charge for only one item. And in the second year onwards I have to charge for 4 items. I tried graduated pricing, but how to offer 3 quantities for no charge for the only first year? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option is [creating a discount (using Coupon)](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/coupons) and apply it for your first year Invoice